# Patch Movement: File Backup and Replace

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm getting an error while trying to copy files from a single source directory which contains bug fixes: `/home/saurabh/testbed/patch_dir/` to multiple destination directories: `app_dir_1` and `app_dir_2`.

Both these directories are exact replicas of each other.

The script does the following:-

1. Read lines from a text file into a list. Each line contains the name of one component. In this case: ['file1.class', file2.html]
2. Search value at each index recursively, starting from a particular directory: 
   `/home/saurabh/testbed/dest_dir/`
3. Take a backup of these files wherever they are found by appending *ddMonyyyy* to their extension.
4. Copy files from directory which contains patched components:   `/home/saurabh/testbed/patch_dir/`
   to the directory where backup was taken earlier

**Directory Overview:-**

`/home/saurabh/testbed/dest_dir/
 |--app_dir_1
    |--file1.class
    |--file2.html
    |--file3.jsp
    |--file4.xml
    |--sub_dir
 |--app_dir_2
    |--file1.class
    |--file2.html
    |--file3.jsp
    |--file4.xml
    |--sub_dir
 |--other_directories

 /home/saurabh/testbed/patch_dir/
 |--file1.class
 |--file2.html`

**Below is my code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import fnmatch
import datetime
import shutil

with open('filenames.txt') as f:
    content = f.readlines()
content = [x.strip() for x in content]
print('File contents:')
print(content)

suffix = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("_%d%b%Y")
approot = '/home/saurabh/testbed/dest_dir/'
source_dir = '/home/saurabh/testbed/patch_dir/'

dir_list = []

print('\n' + 'Renaming files present at:')
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(approot):
    for file_list in content:
        for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, file_list):
            print(os.path.join(root, filename))
            dir_list.append(root)
            current_file = os.path.join(root, filename)
            backup_file = os.path.join(root, filename + suffix)
            os.rename(current_file, backup_file)

print("\n" + "Backup of all files complete!")
print('Backup of ' + str(len(dir_list)) + ' files taken recursively')
print('Number of files mentioned in text file: ' + str(len(content)) + '\n')

# 2 instances in UAT
# 12 instances in PROD
if (2*len(content)) == len(dir_list):
    print("Retrofitted components will be copied to their respective directories")
    for dst_ind in range(0, len(dir_list)):
        if filename in fnmatch.filter(files, file_list):
            print(source_dir + content[dst_ind] + "\t" + dir_list[dst_ind])
            #shutil.copy2(source_dir+content[dst_ind], dir_list[dst_ind])
```

**I'm getting the below error while copying the files (4.)**

```
File contents:
['file1.class', 'file2.html']

Renaming files present at:
/home/saurabh/testbed/dest_dir/app_dir_1/file1.class
/home/saurabh/testbed/dest_dir/app_dir_1/file2.html
/home/saurabh/testbed/dest_dir/app_dir_2/file1.class
/home/saurabh/testbed/dest_dir/app_dir_2/file2.html

Backup of all files complete!
Backup of 4 files taken recursively
Number of files mentioned in text file: 2

Retrofitted components will be copied to their respective directories
/home/saurabh/testbed/patch_dir/file1.class     /home/saurabh/testbed/dest_dir/app_dir_1
/home/saurabh/testbed/patch_dir/file2.html      /home/saurabh/testbed/dest_dir/app_dir_1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./prod_movement.py", line 56, in <module>
    print(source_dir + content[dst_ind] + "\t" + dir_list[dst_ind])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

**Expected Output:**

```
File contents:
['file1.class', 'file2.html']

Renaming files present at:
/home/saurabh/testbed/dest_dir/app_dir_1/file1.class
/home/saurabh/testbed/dest_dir/app_dir_1/file2.html
/home/saurabh/testbed/dest_dir/app_dir_2/file1.class
/home/saurabh/testbed/dest_dir/app_dir_2/file2.html

Backup of all files complete!
Backup of 4 files taken recursively
Number of files mentioned in text file: 2

Retrofitted components will be copied to their respective directories
/home/saurabh/testbed/patch_dir/file1.class     /home/saurabh/testbed/dest_dir/app_dir_1
/home/saurabh/testbed/patch_dir/file2.html      /home/saurabh/testbed/dest_dir/app_dir_1
/home/saurabh/testbed/patch_dir/file1.class     /home/saurabh/testbed/dest_dir/app_dir_2
/home/saurabh/testbed/patch_dir/file2.html      /home/saurabh/testbed/dest_dir/app_dir_2
```

Appreciate any help to fix the code.

Comment: The error you're getting means you're attempting to access an element of a `List` that is beyond the length of the `List`. I'm not saying this will work, but try `print(source_dir + content[dst_ind - 1] + "\t" + dir_list[dst_ind - 1])`

Comment: It works with `print(source_dir + content[dst_ind - 2] + "\t" + dir_list[dst_ind - 2])`. I created a similar `app_dir_3` and using `[dst_ind - 3]` isn't working. The goal is to do this in production where there are 12 instances:- `app_dir_1`, `app_dir_2`, ...., `app_dir_11`, and `app_dir_12`

Comment: You're trying to iterate over `content` and `dir_list` together, but by definition (in the `if` statement), `content` only has half as many members as `dir_list`, so of course you're going to run out of members of `content` and generate that error.

Comment: Yes I understand that. I'm not able to think it through. I had a different idea earlier and my output was `app_dir_1` printed 4 times followed by `app_dir_2` printed 4 times (both at the end)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out !!

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import fnmatch
import datetime
import shutil

with open('filenames.txt') as f:
    content = f.readlines()
content = [x.strip() for x in content]
print('File contents:')
print(content)

suffix = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("_%d%b%Y")
approot = '/Users/saurabhm/Desktop/Python/testbed/dest_dir/'
source_dir = '/Users/saurabhm/Desktop/Python/testbed/patch_dir/'

dir_list = []

print('\n' + 'Renaming files present at:')
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(approot):
    for file_list in content:
        for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, file_list):
            print(os.path.join(root, filename))
            dir_list.append(root)
            current_file = os.path.join(root, filename)
            backup_file = os.path.join(root, filename + suffix)
            #print(current_file, backup_file)
            os.rename(current_file, backup_file)
            #print(source_dir + filename + "\t" + root)
            shutil.copy2(source_dir + filename, root)
            os.chmod(root + '/' + filename, 0o750)

print("\n" + "Backup of all files complete!")
print('Backup of ' + str(len(dir_list)) + ' files taken recursively')
print('Number of files mentioned in text file: ' + str(len(content)) + '\n')
```

Once patched components are received over email, they are copied to a directory in the respective server. All these files are consolidated in a single directory (patch_dir)

Backup of existing files (having the same name and are present in "dest_dir") are taken wherever they are found, following which each file is copied from "patch_dir" to the directories inside "dest_dir", where their backup was taken.